# Intel c++ compiler, ICC, seems to ingnore SSE/AVX seetings

Tags: c++, avx, icc

I have recently downloaded and installed the Intel C++ compiler, Composer XE 2013, for Linux which is free to use for non-commercial development.
http://software.intel.com/en-us/non-commercial-software-development

I'm running on a ivy bridge system (which has AVX).  I have two versions of a function which do the same thing.  One does not use SSE/AVX.  The other version uses AVX.  In GCC the AVX code is about four times faster than the scalar code.  However, with the Intel C++ compiler the performance is much worse.  With GCC I compile like this

```
gcc m6.cpp -o m6_gcc -O3 -mavx -fopenmp -Wall -pedantic
```

With Intel I compile like this

```
icc m6.cpp -o m6_gcc -O3 -mavx -fopenmp -Wall -pedantic
```

I'm only using OpenMP for timing (with `omp_get_wtime()`) at this point.
The strange thing is that if I change the avx option to say `msse2` the code fails to compile with GCC but compiles just fine with ICC.  In fact I can drop the `mavx` all together and it still compiles.  It seems no matter what options I try it compiles but does not make optimal use of the AVX code.  So I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong in enabling/disabling SSE/AVX with ICC?

Here is the the function with AVX that I'm using.

```
inline void prod_block4_unroll2_AVX(double *x, double *M, double *y, double *result) {
    __m256d sum4_1 = _mm256_set1_pd(0.0f);
    __m256d sum4_2 = _mm256_set1_pd(0.0f);

    __m256d yrow[6];
    for(int i=0; i<6; i++) {
        yrow[i] = _mm256_load_pd(&y[4*i]);
    }
    for(int i=0; i<6; i++) {
        __m256d x4 = _mm256_load_pd(&x[4*i]);
        for(int j=0; j<6; j+=2) {
            __m256d brod1 = _mm256_set1_pd(M[i*6 + j]);
            sum4_1 = _mm256_add_pd(sum4_1, _mm256_mul_pd(_mm256_mul_pd(x4, brod1), yrow[j]));
            __m256d brod2 = _mm256_set1_pd(M[i*6 + j+1]);
            sum4_2 = _mm256_add_pd(sum4_2, _mm256_mul_pd(_mm256_mul_pd(x4, brod2), yrow[j+1]));
        }
    }
    sum4_1 = _mm256_add_pd(sum4_1, sum4_2);
    _mm256_store_pd(result, sum4_1);
}
```

Here is timing information in seconds.  I run over three ranges corresponding to L1, L2, and L3 cache ranges.  I only get 4x in the L1 region.  Note that ICC has much faster scalar code but slower AVX code.

```
GCC:
nvec 2000, repeat 100000
time scalar 5.847293
time SIMD 1.463820
time scalar/SIMD 3.994543

nvec 32000, repeat 10000
time scalar 9.529597
time SIMD 2.616296
time scalar/SIMD 3.642400
difference 0.000000

nvec 5000000, repeat 100
time scalar 15.105612
time SIMD 4.530891
time scalar/SIMD 3.333917
difference -0.000000

ICC:
nvec 2000, repeat 100000
time scalar 3.715568
time SIMD 2.025883
time scalar/SIMD 1.834049

nvec 32000, repeat 10000
time scalar 6.128615
time SIMD 3.509130
time scalar/SIMD 1.746477

nvec 5000000, repeat 100
time scalar 9.844096
time SIMD 5.782332
time scalar/SIMD 1.702444
```

Answer (score 1):

Two points:

(1) It appears you are using intel intrinsics in your code -- g++ and icpc do not necessarily implement the same intrinsics (but most of them overlap). Check the header files that need to be imported (g++ may need the hint to define the inartistic for you). Does g++ give an error message when it fails?

(2) The compiler flags do does not mean that instructions will be generated (from icpc --help):
`-msse3    May generate Intel(R) SSE3, SSE2, and SSE instructions`

These flags are usually just hints to the compiler. You may want to look at -xHost and -fast.

> It seems no matter what options I try it compiles but does not make optimal use of the AVX code.

How have you checked this? You may not see a 4x speedup if there are other bottlenecks (such as memory bandwidth).

EDIT (based on question edits):

It looks like icc scalar is faster than gcc scalar -- it is possible that icc is vectorizing the scalar code. If this is the case, I would not expect a 4x speedup from icc when manually coding the vectorization.

As far the the difference between icc at 5.782332s and gcc at 3.509130s (for nvec 5000000); this is unexpected. I cannot tell based on the information I have what why there is a difference in the runtime between the two compilers. I would recommend looking at the emitted code (http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/v2faq/faq8_20.html) from both compilers. Also, make sure that your measurements are reproducible (e.g. memory layout on multi-socket machines, hot/cold caches, background processes, etc.).

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  I'm including "#include <immintrin.h>". GCC says e.g. "__m256d’ was not declared in this scope" if I don't use -mavx.  I tried -xHost -fast -xavx.  It makes no difference.  I'm starting to wonder about the CPU dispatcher with this free version of the intel compiler.  I don't have the full version to compare with.

Comment: According the the FAQ it should include the same features as the commerical version so that's not likely the problem.  "Do the features vary between the non-commercial and commercial product?
At the current time, the non-commercial product offerings have the same features as the commercial product." http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/non-commercial-software-faq/#7

Comment: " GCC says e.g. "__m256d’ was not declared in this scope" if I don't use -mavx." Just means gcc does not define the intrinsic if you do not pass the flag.

Comment: When you say it makes no difference, what are you comparing? Are you comparing the compiled code with and without the -mavx flag?

Comment: okay, but GCC is getting a 4x speedup.  I have the scalar code and the AVX code and I time both.  The intel AVX code is significantly slower than the GCC code (however the Intel scalar code is faster than the GCC scalar code).

Comment: I mean I run my code with the different options I get the same time more or less independent of the options.

Comment: Can you post runtimes for:
icpc scalar, icpc -mavx, gcc scalar, gcc -mavx ?